# Using angularLocalStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying out angularLocalStorage (https://github.com/agrublev/angularLocalStorage) instead of  angular-local-storage because it says that it supports the saving of arrays.

However, I can't seem to work out how to save a one-dimensional array so would appreciate some help.

Localstorage starts off empty so how do I set it as an array so that I can 'push' items to it.

To get the items I use:

```
var items = storage.get('items');
```

but running `typeof` it shows items as an object (not an array).

If I use something like

```
storage.set('items',['testing']);
```

this will just keep adding an array with one value (over-riding the old one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

storage.set() will overwrite the previous value that you stored.
So if you want to push stuff to an array, you should do something like

```
function addToItems(el) {
  var items = storage.get('items') || [];
  items.push(el);
  storage.set('items', items);
}
```

Comment: `storage.get('items') || [];` - never thought of this. Thanks!